# Why simulate click on submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, filemaker

I try this and many others still doesn't work :

I need to use it in the Webviewer with Filemaker (MBS( "WebView.RunJavaScript"; WebViewerRef; Javascript ))

script :      `$("#positiveButtonExpand borRad5 jq-picHover").click(function()`

on webpage :

```
<fieldset>
    <label class="formLabelExpand">Rechercher par numéro de commande :</label>
    <input class="formInputTextMedium resetValue floatLeft borRad5" id="id_1405652204_ScopusIdFilter" name="id_1405652204.ScopusIdFilter" type="text" value="saisissez le n° de la commande">
    <button name="id_1__" type="submit" class="positiveButtonExpand borRad5 jq-picHover">OK</button>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks you for all your answers and advice, no one work for my i think it s come from the website or filemaker. :)

Answer (score 2):

positiveButtonExpand is a class not an ID, you can select it with `.positiveButtonExpand` not `#positiveButtonExpand`.

```
$(".positiveButtonExpand").click(function(){
  // code
});
```

Comment: i try both 
- $('#id_1__').click(function()

-$(".positiveButtonExpand borRad5 jq-picHover").click(function()

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the button by using either:

```
$(".positiveButtonExpand.borRad5.jq-picHover")
```

Or more simply:

```
$(".positiveButtonExpand")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see here is that you're calling the handler on an ID but in your html you have it as a class. For example:

button: `class="positiveButtonExpand borRad5 jq-picHover"`

Javascript: `$("#positiveButtonExpand borRad5 jq-picHover")`

The Javascript needs to be changed to

```
 $(".positiveButtonExpand").click(function(){})
```

When using JQuery and you start a selection with '#', it indicates youre looking for an ID.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to simulate a REAL USER CLICK. To do that, here is a short script.

```
$.fn.simulateClick = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if('createEvent' in document) {
            var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            this.click(); // IE
        }
    });
}
```

This allow to create a native mouse event, so you just simple call the function like this.

```
$(".positiveButtonExpand").simulateClick();
```

Hope that works for you :)